# How to get list of documents with defined value of custom property in Alfresco

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

We use Alfresco Enterprise 4.2.2.5 platform for our projects.

Our users create contracts in Alfresco folder "../contracts_def" and then start process of approvement. 
For a example, folder "contracts_def" has the following structure:

```
Contracts_def (Folder)
   |  
   |---- contract_name1 (Folder)  
   |            |--- contract_name1.docx (main document)  
   |            |--- ext_file1.docx      (document)
   |
   |---- contract_name2 (Folder)
                |--- contract_name2.docx (main document)
                |--- ext_file2.docx      (document)
```

Each main document has set of properties, including status of approvement.
In Alfresco Node browser property's full name is **{httр://www.mytest.ru/model/test/contract/1.0}status**.
I'd like to fetch list of documents with status "on-sign" within folder "contracts_def".

I've wrote simple script for running in Java Script Console:

```
    var rs = search.query
      ({ query:
        "SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:contracts/cm:documentLibrary/cm:contracts/cm:contracts_def//*\"')",
         language:"cmis-alfresco" });
      for (var r in rs)
      { logger.log(rs[r].parent.name + "/" + rs[r].name + "\t" +  rs[r].properties.status); }
```

There are 3 questions:

1) Script works, but Instead of document's status I get "NULL". How I understand, script doesn't return custom property of documents - **{httр://www.mytest.ru/model/test/contract/1.0}status**, but I can get only none-custom properties, for example               **{httр://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}creator**.

2) I'd like to fetch list of documents which have only status "on-sign", but script will return all specified properties without filtering.

How can I change code for my requirements?

3) Can I get this information using built-in web-scripts of Alfresco?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use the regular Alfresco search syntax, rather than the CMIS one?

Comment: I've used Alfresco syntax in script and I get NULL again:

var rs = companyhome.childrenByXPath('st:sites/cm:contracts/cm:documentLibrary/cm:contracts/cm:contracts_def//*');
for (var r in rs)
{logger.log(rs[r].parent.name + "/" + rs[r].name + "\t" + rs[r].properties.status);}

Comment: You'll need to use the qname form when fetching your property in javascript, eg `rs[r].properties["test:status"]`

Comment: Thanks, it works with qname form :) ! In my case also it was neccessary use correct prefix of our custom model (not "test").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you want to use CMIS for this if you are running the code in the server-side JavaScript console which has full access to the JavaScript API and native search.

Rather than using JavaScript and CMIS, you might find it easier to first just get a query working by using the Node Browser available in the admin console.

Go to the admin console, then the node browser, and put this in the search box:

```
PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:contracts/cm:documentLibrary/cm:contracts/cm:contracts_def//*" =test:status:"on-sign"
```

Make sure "fts-alfresco" is selected.

Now that you have a working query, you can go back to the JS console and use it in your search.query call.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpfully!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please remember to accept the answer.